# How to create magento2 custom theme/design

Tags: magento2, template

I am trying to create new custom theme in magento I have followed the official document and did all the changes, I can see my custom theme in admin section too.

Now I need to make some adjustment in header/footer files but not able to find a proper way to do.

I have replaced all the folder on my theme such as below

> app\design\frontend\flow\fa\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view

and tried below also

> app\design\frontend\flow\fa\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view

I am not sure which one is the right but in above all cases still the files are coming from

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml

How can I make to come these files from my folder? I need to override templates to suit my design.

Any view what I am doing wrong? did anyone created any new custom theme and it's working properly?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, as I have seen some question with same heading, but didnt found all of them exactly giving the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you overrid the phtml file in your theme. your template path must be follow

`app\design\frontend\flow\fa\module-catalog\templates\product\view`

Comment: but its still not showing in template path hints, and to confirm I added some text in same file but it is also not showing results. I have cleared the cache as well..

Comment: you have delete `pub/static` and deploy the content. you have to check there is in `pub/static/frontend/flow/fa/module-catalog\templates\product\view\details.phtml` file is created?

Comment: Nothing happened, still the same path showing, though admin and page style is gone now.

Comment: after deploy give 777 permission to files and folder

Comment: checking on local system :(

Comment: you can do it on local too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34586/discussion-between-jack-and-qaisar-satti).